# semantic-symref-filepattern-alist is void until I try to use xref features

Tags: xref, semantic

When I try to use `xref` features, like `xref-find-references`, there would be an error message:

```
Customize `semantic-symref-filepattern-alist’ for js-mode
```

Following [this guide](https://wenijinew.medium.com/emacs-guide-for-beginners-3da882a56740), I add this line to my `init.el` and evaluate that expression only:

```
(add-to-list 'semantic-symref-filepattern-alist '(js-mode "*.js"))
```

This seems to work. However, when I restart my emacs I get the following error message (with debug output):

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable semantic-symref-filepattern-alist)
  (member '(js-mode "*.js") semantic-symref-filepattern-alist)
  (if (member '(js-mode "*.js") semantic-symref-filepattern-alist) semantic-symref-filepattern-alist (setq semantic-symref-filepattern-alist (cons '(js-mode "*.js") semantic-symref-filepattern-alist)))
```

Evaluating that specific expression leads to the error message `the variable "semantic-symref-filepattern-alist" is void`. In order to make this problem go away, I need to try to use an `xref` feature, then re-evaluate that expression. Sometimes it works. Other times, I have to restart emacs and try again. I don't see a pattern, so there's probably something going on underneath that I am not aware of.

**Here's what I have tried**

```
;; Adding this line before dealing semantic-related things did not work
(require 'semantic)

;; for both eval-after-load and with-eval-after-load,
;; same error on start up and using any xref feature won't work
(eval-after-load 'semantic
  (add-to-list 'semantic-symref-filepattern-alist '(js-mode "*.js")))

(with-eval-after-load 'semantic
  (add-to-list 'semantic-symref-filepattern-alist '(js-mode "*.js")))

;; enabling semantic mode in init.el doesn't seem to have an effect
;; in my experiments, I put this line above the add-to-list call.
(semantic-mode 1)

;; adding hooks has no effect
(defun my-setup-semantic-symref ()
  (add-to-list 'semantic-symref-filepattern-alist '(js-mode "*.js")))

(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'my-setup-semantic-symref)

(defun my-setup-semantic-symref ()
  (add-to-list 'semantic-symref-filepattern-alist '(js-mode "*.js")))

(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'my-setup-semantic-symref)

;; this errors by saying that there is no js-mode package found
;; maybe it's because I am using the builtin js-mode of my emacs?
(use-package js-mode
  :config
  (add-to-list 'semantic-symref-filepattern-alist '(js-mode "*.js")))
```

**Context**

I am running emacs Version 29.2 (9.0) on macOS Sonoma Version 14.2.1.
I am using the builtin `js-mode`.

**Solutions I accept**

The best case scenario is that on start up, I am able to use `xref` features like normal on `js-mode`.

The next best thing is that I have an easy way of adding js-mode to the `semantic-symref-filepattern-alist`. As of now, I have been relying on re-evaluating the line `(add-to-list 'semantic-symref-filepattern-alist '(js-mode "*.js"))` in `init.el` with `C-M-x`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are using `semantic-symref-filepattern-alist` before it is defined. You need to `require` the feature that defines it first (or equivalently, load the library that defines it).  Add `(require 'semantic)` *before* the `add-to-list` - or move the `add-to-list` further down in your init file to *after* `semantic` has already been loaded. Untested.

Comment: Thanks @NickD, I gave the `(require 'semantic)` a try, but still same issue.

Comment: Try `(require 'semantic/symref/grep)` instead.

Comment: @NickD, that works, thanks! If you put it up as the answer, I will mark it with the green check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the appropriate `require` before evaluating the `add-to-list` call in your init file:

```el
(require 'semantic/symref/grep)

(add-to-list 'semantic-symref-filepattern-alist '(js-mode "*.js"))
```

---

##### Explanation

Whenever you see a `void variable` error or a `void function` error, there are two possibilities: you have misspelled the name of the variable or the function *OR* the variable (or function) is not defined. In the second case, you have to figure out which library defines it and arrange for that library to be loaded before the variable (or function) can be used. These are very common questions on this site and the answer is almost always the same: `require` the library that defines the variable or function before trying to use it.

The specific problem here is that the variable `semantic-symref-filepattern-alist` is not defined at the time that `(add-to-list 'semantic-symref-filepattern-alist '(js-mode "*.js"))` is evaluated at initialization. `add-to-list` *modifies* the value of an *existing* variable, so it has to know the current value - therefore, the variable *has* to be already defined.

In order for that to happen, the library that defines the variable has to be loaded into Emacs. That can be done either with `require` (or with `load-library`, a somewhat lower-level function) or through the [autoload](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html) mechanism.

When you evaluated the `add-to-list` in your session, apparently all the necessary libraries were already loaded (through one of the mechanisms above), so the evaluation finished without any problem. But when you added the `add-to-list` to your init file and restarted Emacs, your init file was loaded but when it came to the `add-to-list`, the necessary libraries had not been loaded yet and you got the error. That's why adding the `require` before the `add-to-list` in your init file resolves the problem.

The only trick is to know (or find out) *which* library defines the missing variable (or function). In my first comment, I guessed (incorrectly) that `(require 'semantic)` would load the `semantic` library and that would take care of loading any dependent libraries, including the one that defines `semantic-symref-filepattern-alist`, but that didn't work. I then had to go back and find out exactly where the variable was defined. I did `C-h v semantic-symref-filepattern-alist` and (even though the library where it is defined had not been loaded yet), Emacs knew enough to load various libraries where it could be defined and then try to get the doc string of the variable:

```
semantic-symref-filepattern-alist is a variable defined in ‘semantic/symref/grep.el’.

Its value is shown below.

List of major modes and file extension pattern.
See find -name man page for format.
...
```

The path at the end of the first line is actually a link, so you can click it to go to that file. I then checked the bottom of the file for the `provide` form of that file:

```el
...
(provide 'semantic/symref/grep)
...
```

The symbol that is used there, `semantic/symref/grep`, is exactly the symbol that you need to give to `require` in order for it to load that library.